# Is existence of a limit cycles an obstruction for a vector field to be a global Jacobi field?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, limit-cycles

Is there a Riemannian metric on $S^2$ and a vector field $X$ on $S^2$ with the following  two properties?

1. The vector field $X$ is globaly a Jacobi field in the sense that for every point $x\in S^2$ there is a geodesic $\gamma_p$ which joins two singularities of $X$ and $X$ is a Jacobi field allong $\gamma_p$?
2. The vector field $X$ possess a limit cycle

Comment: For your first property, is there supposed to be a relation between the point $x$, and the singularities of $X$? Right now it seems that $x$ is entirely independent of anything else.

Comment: @WillieWong  Yes it is independent.For example consider the Killing vector field generates the rotations around the z-axis.

Comment: You wrote "for every $x\in S^2$ there is a geodesic $\gamma_p$"... are you saying that there is no relationship between $\gamma_p$ and $x$?